# Strive for excellence VS Striving for excellence

Tags: phrases, word-usage

"an environment that promotes strive for excellence / striving for excellence"

I would like to know which one is correct ? Because I dont quite catch how to use the phrase "***strive*** for excellence".

Comment: _Strive_ is a verb.

Answer (score 1):

You need the non-finite *-ing* form: 'striving for excellence'.